# Файлы в python. Количество строк в файле

Tags: python, файлы

Значит у меня есть код:

```
studentsfile = open('dataset_3363_4.txt')
q = 0
for i in studentsfile:
    q+=1 #посчитали количество строк в файле    


lines = studentsfile.readlines()
for k in range(0,q): 
    print(lines[k].split(';'))

studentsfile.close()
```

В нем мне нужно посчитать кол-во строк и в дальнейшем это использовать.
Но второй цикл *for* не работает и выдает ошибку:

```
File "students.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(lines[k].split(';'))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Еще одно НО в том, что этот цикл работает если убрать счетчик строк. Не понимаю в чем дело. Помогите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этой строке вы из файла вычитали все строки из файла и указатель позиции в файле достиг конца:

```
for i in studentsfile:
```

Тут вы снова обращаетесь к тому же файловому объекта, чей указатель в конце, поэтому `lines` будет пустым

```
lines = studentsfile.readlines()
```

---

Решения на месте. Перед `.readlines()`:

- Переоткрыть файл, снова вызвав `open`: `studentsfile = open('dataset_3363_4.txt')`
- Или переместить указатель в начало: `studentsfile.seek(0)`

---

**PS.**

Весь ваш код можно описать так:

```
with open('dataset_3363_4.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines(): 
        print(line.split(';'))
```

Или так:

```
with open('dataset_3363_4.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.split(';'))
```

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек.

Comment: @KirillStepankov, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)